# WPF Datagrid with multiple Column Header Templates

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, datagrid

I have a WPF Datagrid with a custom column header that contains a filter button. My Problem is that in addition to the column headers in my view model another column header is displayed "behind" the other columns. It contains the name of the ViewModel as well as the filter button. How can I get rid of this column?

[image]

Here's my XAML:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}">
    <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="Black">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="15"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="21"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Foreground="White" Grid.Column="0" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
                            <ToggleButton Grid.Column="2" x:Name="Filter" Content="Filter" Height="20"/>
                            <Thumb x:Name="PART_RightHeaderGripper" Grid.Column="3"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                            Width="2" BorderThickness="1"
                            BorderBrush="{Binding VerticalGridLinesBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                            Cursor="SizeWE"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

And my ViewModel:

```
var _customers = new List<Customer>...;
Customers = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_customers);
```

I know I can get the unwanted header to be empty, by overriding the `ToString()` function to return an empty string, but I'd rather like to use a plain black template without the button.

Comment: Idk if it qualifies as a "duplicate" My question was aimed in a slightly different direction. Regardless, your link gave me the insight I needed to solve my problem. Thanks!

Comment: it is great. btw, you could have posted your own solution as answer